# Intellisense warning: Incomplete type is not allowed (in inline method but defintion of type is in cpp)

Tags: c++

I've forward declared my enum class, definition is in cpp, program compiles but I'm getting a red "wave" under the type name (below in inline method)

I would like to ask if it's recomended to move that inlined method into cpp file?
I'm a hoby programer so I don't know whether is this inlined method with incomplete type in a header file ok or not.

header file:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;
enum class MinimumName;

    class Limits
    {
    public:
        Limits(TableLayout layout);
        void SetMinimum(MinimumName name, unsigned int minimum);

// other stuff irrelevant

    private:
        typedef map<MinimumName, unsigned int> MinContainer;
MinContainer::iterator Miniter;
        MinContainer Minimums;
};
                                   //intelisence warning here in argument list
inline void Limits::SetMinimum(MinimumName name, unsigned int minimum)
{                             // incomplete type is not allowed
    Miniter = Minimums.find(name);
    Miniter->second = minimum;
}
```

cpp file

```
enum class MinimumName
{
    Inside,
    Outside,
    Table
};
```

shall I move it into cpp file or not? and why?

Comment: Intellisense warning, in my opinion, are irrelevant. They're *very often* incorrect. What does the compiler say?

Comment: Does that mean my code abowe is fully correct? Compiler says nothing.

Comment: I've not seen it completely. As I said, why does your compiler say?

Comment: It's better to put `inline` keyword inside the class before method declaration.

Comment: GCC doesn't complain if I comment out the lines with types you didn't provide and include the header from a file with just main.

Comment: @iammilind thanks, puting the inline keyword inside the class acctauly removes a warning :D (I'm not sure if is that temprary or not, though)... chris, thanks for testing, so visual studio gives wrong intellisence warnings, ok...

Comment: Side note: you really should use the `using` keyword in the global scope like that in a header file.

Comment: The IntelliSense parser has the same problem as any other .cpp file that tries to use this inline function.  It doesn't have the definition of the enum.  So it can never actually use the function.  Either move the enum into the header file or move the function into the .cpp file.

Comment: Cornstalks, yeah I know, allready changed :) Thanks Hans for input, I've allready put the enum into the header because of other circumstances...

Comment: @iammilind it is worth to put your comment into an answer, it helps the OP and SO too, and others who wanna find unanswered questions, too. I can see this question is answered already.

Comment: @BarnabasSzabolcs, I have added the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

If a `class` method (or for that matter any function) has to be put in a header file which is going to be included by several .cpp files then it has to be `inline`.

This `inline` does not necessarily mean the usual macro style inlining. The macro style inlining is decided by compiler and the programmer doesn't have much control over it.
This `inline` keyword is the guaranteed effect where only one definition is generated for all the .cpp file. Effectively the `inline` *keyword* maintains the [ODR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_definition_rule).

AFAIK, *conventionally* a method has to be made `inline` (for ODR purpose) when it's declared inside the class. So once you make the method `inline` inside the class everything should work fine without error/warning. Later on putting `inline` keyword for method definition outside the class is redundant.